# How do I use the RailsAdmin.authorize_with method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, warden

I installed the rails admin gem, and have it working with Devise easily enough. I want to authorize the user via a boolean value, since not all users are admin. Though I'm not sure where to place the code or how it's supposed to work. i took the code from the readme, and have this currently:

```
RailsAdmin.authenticate_with do
  redirect_to root_path unless request.env['warden'].user.is_admin?
end
```

But the .user method call comes up nil, so the is_admin? fails.

Any recommendations on how I can set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realized i just needed it in the application_controller

```
RailsAdmin.authorize_with do
  redirect_to root_path unless warden.user.is_admin?
end
```

Comment: thanks. sigh... if rails ever gave proper documentation, i would praise them. there's no proper tutorial or anything on the goddamn rails admin

Comment: You can also use mainapp.root_path,  if root_path doenst work right away